# How can I move customer community from one Dev org to another?

Tags: customer-community

How can I move customer community from one Dev org to another Dev org. I use maven mate and eclipse to move meta data.

Comment: Hi Ankit, welcome to SFSE. Please take a moment to scroll through the [tour] and read [ask]. Please note the purpose of a title is to convey your issue *as concisely as possible*. Adding greetings in your title is wildly off topic. Greetings aren't really on topic in the body of your posts either. Stick to information.

Answer (score 1):

You can move community using Eclipse IDE. You can follow the steps given here.

[Migrate Your Community with Change Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrate_changesets.htm&type=5)

The only difference here is instead of Change set you will use Eclipse IDE. In the IDE Select the Network component type, choose your community, and then add it. Select all the dependency as well and then deploy it to another org. There are some prerequisite steps as well which you need to follow as well.

If it is a Lightning Community you can follow steps here : [Ways to Deploy Lightning Communities](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250156&language=en_US&type=1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Tushar. I was not sure that communities comes under Network component. Do you know what is communities component in IDE is for ?

Comment: @AnkitMunhet That [Community will be this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_community.htm).I am not quite sure here. But you will find community under Network.

Comment: was able to move the community to new dev org however when i am opening the builder it is giving me error - Cannot read property 'get' of undefined. When I login to community from the URL - An internal server error has occurred
An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. If you believe you have additional information that may be of help in reproducing or correcting the error, please contact Salesforce Support.

Comment: @AnkitMunhet did you follow all steps correctly. Including create a new community?

Comment: Ok ! I read it now that you need to create it with the same name. However when doing it with eclipse it created community with the same name in the target org.

Answer (score 0):

You need [Data Loader](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Data_Loader):

> The Force.com platform offers you a development environment which you can use to create your own custom applications. Frequently, you will use the Force.com platform to create applications that operate on data that you already have in some form - in comma-separated variable files, spreadsheets or other relational databases.
>
> The Data Loader is an easy to use graphical tool that helps you to get your data into Salesforce objects. The Data Loader can also be used to extract data from database objects into any of the destinations mentioned above. You can even use the Data Loader to perform bulk deletions by exporting the ID fields for the data you wish to delete and using that source to specify deletions through the Data Loader.
>
> The Data Loader requires the use of the Force.com API. If your Salesforce edition allows the use of the API (Enterprise, Unlimited and Developer Editions), you can download the Data Loader from the Setup menu, under Administer heading - Data Management.

Comment: The question is around moving metadata and not data here .